# If I have an m-by-n matrix, and a non zero m-dimensional vector $y$ such that $y^TA = 0^T$, can the rows of A to be linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

[image]

I am trying to write a proof regarding the following question and am stumped on this particular version of the problem. I believe that I have written a correct proof when asked if the *columns* of A are linearly dependent. That is solved by showing that the non-zero vector y can be used as a nontrivial solution of linear dependence. But I don't really know how this information translates when analyzing the rows of A instead. I tried to look for a counterexample that IS linearly independent but cant find one.

Comment: Taking the transpose of both sides of $y^TA=0^T$ gives $A^Ty=0$.  If you can show that implies the columns of $A^T$ are linearly dependent, then you have shown that the rows of $A$ are linearly dependent as well.  (Also, for the stated problem the columns of $A$ need not be dependent - in the case $n=1$, $A$ could be a single nonzero column vector for that matter, with $y$ orthogonal to $A$).

Comment: @MW So would a valid example of linearly independent rows of A be $A= \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ where $y^TA = 0$ in this case would the "rows" of A being $(1) and (0)$ be considered linearly independent?

Comment: Doing a quick search led me to find out that the first "row" of A being $(1)$ would be linearly independent. Is it enough to show that 1 of its rows is linearly independent for me to disprove the statement?

Comment: In your example the rows are dependent, which is consistent with what I said and what you are trying to prove. The *columns* (technically column, singular) for $A$ are (“is”) independent, since there is only one and it is a nonzero vector.  As to your second statement, no, the rows of a column vector with more than one entry can never be independent.  I don’t know what you mean by “1 of its rows are linearly independent”.  To disprove the statement (which can’t be done since statement is true) you would have to show set of ***all*** rows is independent.

Answer (score 1):

We can write $A$ as
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
- & a_1 & - \\
& \vdots & \\
- & a_m & -
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the $a_i$ are the row vectors making up $A$.
Then if $y_i$ is the $i$-th entry of $y$ we have $\textbf{0}^T = y^TA = \sum_{i=1}^m y_ia_i$. But since $y$ is non-zero, there is an entry $y_j \neq 0$ of $y$, and so the rows of $A$ are linearly independent.

If you already understand the column vector case, then as mentioned in the comments you can take the transpose of both sides to get $A^Ty = \textbf{0}$. Then the columns of $A^T$ are exactly the rows of $A$, that is
$$
A^T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\vert &  & \vert \\
a_1^T & \dots & a_m^T \\ 
\vert &  & \vert 
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and therefore since $y$ is non-zero and $A^Ty = \textbf{0}$, the columns of $A^T$ (rows of $A$) are linearly independent.

Comment: Wouldnt this prove linear dependance? Since there is always a non zero $y$ in $\sum _{i=1}^m y_ia_i$ which causes $y^TA = 0$?

Comment: Yep it would prove linear dependence. This is what the claim says to show. Also, you won't be able to find a counter example since it doesn't exist, due to the claim being true.

Answer (score 0):

$$y^TA=0^T$$
row by row multiplication:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}{y_ic_i(A)}=0$$
$$\overrightarrow$$
the columns of A are linearly dependent